# Vue2 call a method of other component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a method: openMenu() in component A.

I want to call this method in component B.

There are $root, Event bus, and Vuex, what should I do in this case?

What is the best practice?

Comment: You could pass it as props? But why would you want to do that instead of definining a common util function outside of the components, and calling them within?

Comment: Don't fall in best practice trap. All the options mentioned above has specific use-cases but achieve the same result. Go with $root. It's quick & simple.

Comment: @cSharp, I can't move this method into common, it relates some logic in the A component.

Comment: @power-cut, the project already applied Vuex, what is about Vuex for this case?

Comment: @Park If you want to call openMenu() in Vuex you need to move it to Vuex `actions`. This way openMenu() will be exposed to entire app. Different approach but same result as mentioned by @cSharp.

Comment: @power-cut I just want to apply same this example  https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-gdme1g?file=index.js , thank you anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the emit.

in the component A:

```
mounted() {
 this.$root.$on("callMyMethod", () => {
   this.myMethod();
 });
},
methods: {
  myMethod() {
    // do something
  },
},
```

and in the component B:

```
methods: {
 doSomething() {
    this.$root.$emit("callMyMethod");
  },
},
```